# Working with remotely loaded class SWF from another domain

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, cross-domain

This is **not** about loading SWFs from the same domain.

There's a small SWF file that's supposed to load/save data from/to a `SharedObject`. It's residing in a dedicated domain (let's call it domain A).

There are several applications that need to access the data mentioned above in a shared manner (i.e. all applications from different domains (B,C,D,...). Naturally, using a `SharedObject` from within the application won't do, since the `SharedObject` is per-domain.

- From the application in domain B I am loading the policy file from domain A. The policy file allows all domains via "*" and the domain "B" specifically.
- I am allowing the domain A via `allowDomain("A")` in the application
- I am allowing the domain B inside the data processing SWF via `allowDomain("B")`
- I am adding the **loaderContext** like so: `new LoaderContext(true, new ApplicationDomain(), SecurityDomain.currentDomain);`. I explicitly need the loaded SWF to retain it's own domain "A" context, so that the `SharedObject` will be written on "A" namespace rather than the hosting application's one ("B"), hence the "`new ApplicationDomain()`"

The data processing SWF is loaded using `SWFLoader`.

If I understand correctly, all of the above should enable accessing the loaded SWF's class members. As you might have guessed by now, it doesn't really work. When I'm trying to cast the SWFLoader's content as the SWF's document class, it's `null` due to security issues (I tried loading with `ApplicationDomain.currentDomain` and it worked perfectly, so I know the class is the same, but it's not what I need)

What am I missing?
Or is there a better solution to share data locally between applications on different domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jodieorourke.com/view.php?id=115&blog=news

Apparently, overdoing security is bad.